# Received error 'objects are not valid as a React child' while mapping an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

Errors: -

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {0}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

##### Code

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Cou extends React.Component {
  state = {
    Api1: [],
    Api2: [],
    Api3: [],
    Api4:[],
    currentTask:"",
  }

  componentDidMount() { 
    axios.get("https://assessment.api.vweb.app/users")
    .then(res => { const Api1 = res.data; this.setState({ Api1 }); }) 
    axios.get("https://assessment.api.vweb.app/products")
    .then(res => { const Api2 = res.data; this.setState({ Api2}); })
    axios.get("https://assessment.api.vweb.app/orders")
    .then(res => { const Api3 = res.data.map(item => ({...item, user_name: this.state.Api1.find(({user_id}) => user_id === item.user_id)?.name || "", product_name: this.state.Api2.find(({product_id}) => product_id === item.product_id)?.name|| "",})); this.setState({ Api3 }); })
  }

  handleChange = (e) =>
  {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    this.setState({
      currentTask:e.target.value,
    });
  };
  
  show = () =>{
    let cn = this.state.Api1.filter(m=>{return m.user_id == `${this.state.currentTask}`}).map(o=>{return((o.name))})
    let cd = this.state.Api3.filter(person => { return person.user_id == `${this.state.currentTask}`}).map(n => {return (n.product_name)})
    this.setState({
      Api4:[{coustomer_name: {...cn}}, {coustomer_detail:{...cd}}]
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div>
          <input type ="text" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          <button onClick={this.show}> Show history</button>
          {this.state.Api4.map(p=>{return (<p>{p.coustomer_name} {console.log(p.coustomer_name)} bought,</p>)})}
          {this.state.Api4.map(p=>{return (<p>{p.coustomer_detail} {console.log(p.coustomer_detail)}</p>)})}
        </div>
      </>)
  }
}
```

3.Console log of api4 arr
[image]

How to solve these errors. Here i am trying to print the data from array Api4 but the above errors are coming.

The problem is in printing the data from the array Api4. In show function i took value of cn and cd and put in array Api 4. Then while mapping the values from Api4 i got these errors.(The error is related to either in the way of storing values of cn and cd in Api4 or in mapping of Api4 for print).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with this line:

```
Api4:[{coustomer_name: {...cn}}, {coustomer_detail:{...cd}}]
```

which converts the output `cd` array again into an object where keys are just the array indexes.

And you should use `find` instead of `filter` to find the customer name.

You can actually simplify the whole code like this:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default class Cou extends React.Component {
  state = {
    Api1: [],
    Api2: [],
    Api3: [],
    Api4: [],
    currentTask: ""
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("https://assessment.api.vweb.app/users").then((res) => {
      const Api1 = res.data;
      this.setState({ Api1 });
    });
    axios.get("https://assessment.api.vweb.app/products").then((res) => {
      const Api2 = res.data;
      this.setState({ Api2 });
    });
    axios.get("https://assessment.api.vweb.app/orders").then((res) => {
      const Api3 = res.data.map((item) => ({
        ...item,
        user_name:
          this.state.Api1.find(({ user_id }) => user_id === item.user_id)
            ?.name || "",
        product_name:
          this.state.Api2.find(
            ({ product_id }) => product_id === item.product_id
          )?.name || ""
      }));
      this.setState({ Api3 });
    });
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    this.setState({
      currentTask: e.target.value
    });
  };

  show = () => {
    let cn = this.state.Api1.find((m) => {
      return m.user_id == `${this.state.currentTask}`;
    })?.name;
    let cd = this.state.Api3.filter((person) => {
      return person.user_id == `${this.state.currentTask}`;
    }).map((n) => {
      return n.product_name;
    });

    this.setState({
      Api4: { coustomer_name: cn, coustomer_detail: cd }
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div>
          <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <button onClick={this.show}> Show history</button>
          <br />
          {this.state.Api4?.coustomer_name && (
            <>
              <h2>{`${this.state.Api4?.coustomer_name} bought,`}</h2>
              {this.state.Api4?.coustomer_detail?.map((p) => {
                return <p>{p}</p>;
              })}
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Working Demo

[image: Edit vigilant-voice-hkzt15]

Comment: i had a question that how Api4 is getting all the elements of cd without spread operator. And is there any difference between . and .? here {this.state.Api4?.coustomer_name}

Comment: @VisheshKumar, cd is arleady an array output from filter function. `?.` this is called optional chaining operator which is safe when you have null or undefined values check the docs here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: thank you @Amila Senadheera for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

In your function `show` you assig to Api4 properties `Api4:[{coustomer_name: {...cn}}, {coustomer_detail:{...cd}}]` they are objects. As React said to you, you can't use object as React.Child. You should handle object for instance cast it to array with `Object.values(cn)` and React will render your array of names (without comma).

And then you can loop through your array and style it like so: `coustomer_name.map(name => <div>{name}</div>)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are getting that error because you are trying to map the response object that you received from the request. Try to first extract the data into an array and then pass it to Api4

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it what you are trying to do ?

```
    show = () =>{
  const cn = this.state.Api1.find(m => m.user_id == `${this.state.currentTask}`)?.name || ""
  const cd = this.state.Api3.find(m => m.user_id == `${this.state.currentTask}`)?.product_name || ""
  this.setState({
    Api4:[{coustomer_name: cn}, {coustomer_detail: cd}]
  })
}
```

Comment: I checked this code. The problem with this code is that when we save cd without spread operator it takes the first value and saves it in Api4. So due to that we only get first value. For example if i put value 20 then it should display name of person and then the list of all the items he buys. But here we would only get only the name of person and only one item.

Comment: Oh ok sorry I thought you wanted just one value

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Cou extends React.Component {
    state = {
        Api1: [],
        Api2: [],
        Api3: [],
        Api4: [],
        currentTask: "",
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get("https://assessment.api.vweb.app/users")
            .then(res => { const Api1 = res.data; this.setState({ Api1 }); })
        axios.get("https://assessment.api.vweb.app/products")
            .then(res => { const Api2 = res.data; this.setState({ Api2 }); })
        axios.get("https://assessment.api.vweb.app/orders")
            .then(res => { const Api3 = res.data.map(item => ({ ...item, user_name: this.state.Api1.find(({ user_id }) => user_id === item.user_id)?.name || "", product_name: this.state.Api2.find(({ product_id }) => product_id === item.product_id)?.name || "", })); this.setState({ Api3 }); })
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.value);
        this.setState({
            currentTask: e.target.value,
        });
    };

    show = () => {
        let cn = this.state.Api1.filter(m => { return m.user_id == `${this.state.currentTask}` }).map(o => { return ((o.name)) })
        let cd = this.state.Api3.filter(person => { return person.user_id == `${this.state.currentTask}` }).map(n => { return (n.product_name) })
        var api4 = []
        for (var i = 0; i < cn.length; i++) {
            api4.push({ 'coustomer_name': cn[i], 'coustomer_detail': cd[i] })
        }
        this.setState({
            Api4: api4
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <button onClick={this.show}> Show history</button>
                    {this.state.Api4.map(p => { return (<p>{p.coustomer_name} bought,</p>) })}
                    {this.state.Api4.map(p => { return (<p>{p.coustomer_detail}</p>) })}
                </div>
            </>)
    }

}
```

Comment: I checked this code. The problem with this code is that when we save cd without spread operator it takes the first value and saves it in Api4. So due to that we only get first value. For example if i put value 20 then it should display name of person and then the list of all the items he buys. But here we would only get only the name of person and only one item.